# How to find the valid time if StartTime and EndTime is given?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

How can the method be implemented in C#?

```cs
string StartTime = "06:10 PM";
string Endtime = "08:10 PM";
DateTime current_time = DateTime.Now;
 
bool validTime = validTimeFindout(StartTime,Endtime,current_time);
```

```
bool validTimeFindout(string StartTime, string Endtime,DateTime current_time){
    // This method should return true 
    // when the current_time>= StartTime && current_time<=Endtime 
    // otherwise false
}
```

I tried to find out the valid time in the specific range and for that validTimeFindout method will help and here the method is comparing the time get from local pc and compare them with StartTime and Endtime

Answer (score 1):

Starting with .NET 6, you can use the [TimeOnly Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly):

```cs
static bool IsTimeBetween(string startTime, string endTime, DateTime dateTime)
{
    if (TimeOnly.TryParse(startTime, out var t1) &&
        TimeOnly.TryParse(endTime, out var t2))
    {
        return TimeOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime).IsBetween(t1, t2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that [`TimeOnly.IsBetween`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly.isbetween?view=net-7.0#system-timeonly-isbetween(system-timeonly-system-timeonly)) supports time ranges that span midnight such as 23:00-01:00.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the inputs from `string to datetime` and do the calculations: [datetime.parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0)

```
    bool validTimeFindout(string StartTime, string Endtime, DateTime current_time)
    {
        DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Parse(StartTime);
        DateTime _endTime = DateTime.Parse(Endtime);
        if (current_time >= _startTime && current_time <= _endTime)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: I believe the Q is about comparing the time of day only

Comment: @KlausGütter 
`DateTime.Parse(StartTime)`  If it is only time input, it will return today's date and input time. In fact, only time is compared...

Comment: It give me error and says operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'DateTime'

Comment: Should be <= not =<

Comment: @KlausGütter tank you ... i edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse()` method to parse a string into the `DateTime` datatype.
`DateTime` datatypes can be compared as numeric datatypes with `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, `>`

```
bool validTimeFindout(string StartTime, string Endtime, DateTime current_time){
    DateTime start;
    DateTime.TryParse(StartTime, out start);
    DateTime end;
    DateTime.TryParse(Endtime, out end);
    return current_time >= start && current_time <= end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert those strings to DateTime objects.
Then you should compare those DateTime objects and current time.

```
using System.Globalization;

string StartTime = "06:10 PM";
string Endtime = "08:10 PM";
DateTime current_time = DateTime.Now;

try {
   bool validTime = validTimeFindout(StartTime, Endtime, current_time);
   Console.WriteLine(validTime);
}catch(Exception exc) { 
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}

bool validTimeFindout(string StartTime, string Endtime, DateTime current_time) {
    DateTime start = ParseTimeString(StartTime);
    DateTime end = ParseTimeString(Endtime);
    if(current_time.CompareTo(start) >= 0 && current_time.CompareTo(end) <= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

DateTime ParseTimeString(string timeString) {
    string format = "hh:mm tt";
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(timeString, format, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result)) {
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Cannot parse time!");
    }
}
```

There are also several things you can rethink and fix.

1. Naming pattern - IMHO is valid is not a good name for method checking if a DateTime is between other DateTimes.
2. Use single naming convention and stick to it. The most popular convention in C# is cammel case (like startTime).
3. Is it really needed to store those DateTimes in strings formatted like "01:10 PM"? Why doesn't you simply store DateTime objects?

Comment: IMHO why use `TryParseExact` if you go ahead and throw an exception on parse error. At this point you could have used `ParseExact` which will throw an exception if parsing failed.

Comment: @RandRandom I've thrown an exception because it's only an example in real life there should be a reaction to error (e. g. trying to convert the time using a different format or checking if the string contains any forbidden character and removing or changing it. But of course if you do not want to use custom behavior on error you can use ParseExact().